# Вывод на экран с помощью obj.inspect (в консоли)

Tags: ruby

Как в ruby делать аналогичный вывод на экран с помощью obj.inspect в консоли для этого объекта:

```
ruby -e "p 'hello world!'"
```

Или `obj.inspect` не предназначен для консоли?

Comment: p 'hello world!' это сокращенная запись puts 'hello world!'.inspect. Оба метода можно использовать для консольного вывода. Пока не очень понятно, что вызывает затруднение?

Comment: Без .inspect тоже работает. Тогда зачем его указать?

Comment: Затем, что с `.inspect` и без него вывод разный. Как по содержанию, так и по смыслу.

Answer (score 1):

В [документации к `Kernel.p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p) ясно написано:

> For each object, directly writes `obj.inspect` followed by a newline to the program’s standard output.
>
> ---
>
> Для каждого объекта выводит `obj.inspect` и следом перевод строки в стандартный вывод.

[`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) же вообще не занимается выводом:

> Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of `obj`.
>
> ---
>
> Возвращает строку, содержащую человекочитаемое представление `obj`.

...а у `String` унаследованный у `Object` [метод `inspect` переопределён](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-inspect):

> Returns a printable version of str, surrounded by quote marks, with special characters escaped.
>
> ---
>
> Возвращает пригодную к выводу версию `str`, окружённую кавычками и с экранированными спецсимволами.

...получая тем самым литерал заданной строки, пригодный для вставки в Ruby-код. Если смотреть на содержимое строк, выводимое с помощью `puts`:

- исходная строка содержит `hello world`
- строка`.inspect` содержит `"hello world"`
- строка`.inspect.inspect` содержит `"\"hello world\""`, поскольку в инспектируемой строке были двойные кавычки, в этой форме они были экранированы

Видите закономерность?